# Rtmp on Apache support. Can't seem to find any information on it

Tags: apache, streaming, rtmp

I am trying to set up a streaming service that uses rtmp and all of the online guides point to nginx. I would really however want to stay with Apache if it is at all possible.
Yet i have not found any information.
If this is possible how would it be done?